# Getting response times

Tags: scala, http, scala-dispatch

Is there a simple way to get the response time for a request to a url (other than keeping track of time in the code separately)?

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

val svc = dispatch.url(url)
  val response: Future[com.ning.http.client.Response] = Http(svc > (x => x))
  response onComplete {
    case Success(content) => {
      println(s"SUCCESS: ${content.getStatusCode()} for $url")
      //how long did this take??
 }
    case Failure(t) => {
      println(s"ERROR: timeout/failure for $url")
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is wrong wrapping it and using the wrapper when you need the response time?

Comment: Nothing I guess: how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different approach for computing the elapsed time, might need a bit more customization (like handling of failure, `NonFatal` most probably), but I think this is a bit more idiomatic. It works only with `Future`s though.

First create a class for the result with time (could be replaced with a tuple too) and one for the failure with time.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class ResultWithTime[ResultType](val result: ResultType, val time: Long)

class FailureWithTime(failure: Throwable, val time: Long) extends Throwable(failure)
```

Then create a method that wraps the future to execute and handles the case when it fails (might use `Promise` if you do not like the `Future`'s `map` and `recoverWith` methods (as they require an implicit `ExecutionContext`)).

```
object TimerFuture {
  def apply[ResultType](fut: =>Future[ResultType]): Future[ResultWithTime[ResultType]] = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
    fut.map(r => ResultWithTime(r, System.currentTimeMillis - startTime))
       .recoverWith{case t:Throwable =>
         Future.failed(new FailureWithTime(t, System.currentTimeMillis - startTime))
         }
  }
}
```

Here is an example how to use it:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.io.StdIn


object Y extends App {
   TimerFuture(Future{Thread.sleep(200); "Hello"})
     .onSuccess({case ResultWithTime(r, t) => println(s"Took $t ms to get: $r")})
   TimerFuture(Future{Thread.sleep(100); throw new NullPointerException()})
     .onFailure({case f: FailureWithTime => println(s"Took ${f.time} ms to get: ${f.getCause}")})
   StdIn.readLine()
}
```

Comment: I should add if you do not like this implementation, [rapture-core](https://github.com/propensive/rapture-core)'s modes provide an alternative using `implicit val handler = modes.returnFuture compose modes.timeExecution`.

Comment: Where could I find a complete code example for doing this with rapture-core? I tried the examples from the readlme, but I couldn't get them to work

Comment: @EmilD I think the example above should work for the call site. Or you mean [how to write a method](https://github.com/propensive/rapture-core#writing-methods-to-use-modes) that could be used this way? Or [wrap existing methods](https://github.com/propensive/rapture-core#conveniences-for-existing-methods)?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code with something like this (not tested):

```
class Timer[ResultType](computation: =>Future[ResultType]) {
  private val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  val result: Future[ResultType] = computation
  private var endTime: Option[Long] = None
  result.onComplete{case _ => endTime = Some(System.currentTimeMillis)}
  def responseTime: Option[Long] = endTime.map(_ - startTime)
  //probably also provide onComplete and other Future methods wrapping result.
}

object Timer{
  def apply[ResultType](computation: =>Future[ResultType]) = {
    new Timer(computation)
  }
}
```

You can create more specific timers with factory methods in companion objects to help working with the computations you want to measure.

Usage:

```
val timedComputation = Timer{Http(svc > (x => x))}
timedComputation.result.onComplete{case _ => ???}
//In a completed event:
val responseTimeInMillis: Long = timedComputation.responseTime.get
```

Comment: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
[error] class Timer[ResultType](val computation: => Future[ResultType]) {

Comment: In the companion object it complains about "def apply(computation: =>Future[ResultType]) ={"  It works with "def apply(computation: => Future[com.ning.http.client.Response]) = {"

Comment: Silly me. I forget to add the generic parameter there. Updated.